# How can I override a function from pytest that is injected into my test function arguments?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using [snapshottest package](https://github.com/syrusakbary/snapshottest) to add the possibility of tests using snapshots. This has added a lot of value and speed to our tests.

This works this way:

```py
def test_my_fn(foo, bar, snapshot):
    snapshot.assert_match(my_fn(foo, bar))
```

The first time the test run, snapshot will save the output of `my_fn(foo, bar)` and then, every time the test runs, it will check the output of `my_fn(foo, bar)` with the saved snapshot.

However, I'm having a problem with the way `snapshot.assert_match` saves the object. I'm working with [shapely geometries](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) and snapshot doesn't write the shapely objects out of the box. It saves as `<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x1000000>` which make tests fail under other circumstances.

So I wrote a function `dump_geometry` that converts the geometry into an dictionary, and then, `snapshot.assert_match` can properly write the snapshot.

I make it work by doing:

```py
def test_my_fn(foo, bar, snapshot):
    snapshot.assert_match(dump_geometry(my_fn(foo, bar)))
```

This works fine, but I must add this to every test I have. I wanted to know if there's a way to overwrite `snapshot.assert_match` to first call `dump_geometry` and then, following with the original `snapshot.assert_match`.

I have no clue on how to do this. I've tried to use a fixture but no progress.

Oh, I might add that I would like this to be the normal behaviour of `snapshot.assert_match`. I mean, to be global.

---

EDIT 1: As per @BorrajaX comment, I'll add up more info:

I dont't have only my_fn, but hundreds of functions that fill up this scenario. I also use `mark.parametrize` to run the same test with diff inputs:

```py
@mark.parametrize('foo, bar', [(1,2), (2, 3), (4, 5)])
def test_my_fn(foo, bar, snapshot):
    snapshot.assert_match(dump_geometry(my_fn(foo, bar)))


@mark.parametrize('foo, bar, baz', [
   ('a',shapely.geometry.Polygon(), [1,2.3]),
   ('b',shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon(), [1.7,2,6]), 
   ('c',shapely.geometry.LineString(), [])])
def test_my_fn2(foo, bar, baz, snapshot):
    snapshot.assert_match(dump_geometry(my_fn2(foo, bar, baz)))


@mark.parametrize('foo', [
   (shapely.geometry.MultiLineString()), 
   (shapely.geometry.LineString()), 
   (shapely.geometry.Polygon()), ])
def test_my_fn3(foo, bar, snapshot):
    snapshot.assert_match(dump_geometry(my_fn3(foo, bar)))
```

I wanted to avoid writing `snapshot.assert_match(dump_geometry(...))` at every test making `dump_geometry` be automatically called when `snapshot.assert_match` is called, either by overring it or whatever other way.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but jave you considered creating a partial function and fill it up with `my_fn(foo, bar)` or something along those lines?
https://www.learnpython.org/en/Partial_functions

Comment: @BorrajaX Great to know this, however, I don't believe I can use this. Those tests are managed by pytest and they have many different inputs. Also it's not only function as my_fn. There are hundreds of functions being tested that are under this case.